# Changing a mutable field in OCaml

Tags: syntax-error, ocaml

When I run the following code I get a syntax error, although as far as I can tell the syntax is correct.  This attempts to implement a queue structure, where the function `from_list` converts a list to a queue with the corresponding values.  I wrote `str_of_int_q` to print the contents of a queue.  `x` and `y` are supposed to be two nodes, with `x` at the head and `y` at the tail.

```
;; open Assert

type 'a qnode = {v: 'a;
                 mutable next: 'a qnode option}
type 'a queue = {mutable head: 'a qnode option;
                 mutable tail: 'a qnode option}

let from_list (l: 'a list) : 'a queue =
  let rec loop (l2: 'a list) (qu: 'a queue) =
    begin match l2 with
    | [] -> qu
    | [x] -> let y = {v = x; next = None} in
             qu.head <- Some y; qu.tail <- Some y;
             qu
    | h1::h2::t -> let y = qu.head in
                   let z = {v = h1; next = y} in
                   qu.head <- Some z;
                   qu
    end
  in loop l {head = None; tail = None}

let str_of_int_q (q: int queue) : string =
  let rec loop (r: int qnode option) (s: string) : string =
    begin match r with
    | None -> s
    | Some n -> loop n.next (s ^ (string_of_int n.v))
    end
  in loop q.head ""

let x = {v = 1; next = None}
let y = {v = 2; next = None}
x.next <- Some y;
let z = {head = Some x; tail = Some y}
;; print_endline (str_of_int_q z)
```

---

My error:

```
line 32, characters 7-9:
Error: Syntax error
```

Line 32 is the line `x.next <- Some y;` and characters 7-9 indicate the `<-`.  But I'm storing into a mutable field an object of the appropriate type, so I don't see what's going wrong.

Comment: Does it work if you put `;;` before `x.next`?

Comment: @melpomene Huh, it did when I put `;;` before `x.next` and then took `;` off of the end.  I don't understand exactly why that works, but great to see that it does.  Put this as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Top-level statements are separated by `;;` in OCaml. However, `;;` is optional before several keywords, such as `let`, `open`, `type`, etc. This is why you don't need `;;` most of the time.

In your case, `;;` is needed to disambiguate between `let y = {v = 2; next = None}` and `x.next <- Some y`. The latter is an expression and doesn't start with a special keyword, so OCaml doesn't know to insert an implicit `;;` here.

See also http://ocaml.org/learn/tutorials/structure_of_ocaml_programs.html#The-disappearance-of.

As explained there, you can either do

```
let y = {v = 2; next = None}
;; x.next <- Some y
```

or

```
let y = {v = 2; next = None}
let () = x.next <- Some y
```

This latter solution works because by introducing a dummy binding we're starting our statement with `let`, which disambiguates again.

Note: I've also removed the trailing `;` from your code. `;` is [actually an infix operator](http://ocaml.org/learn/tutorials/structure_of_ocaml_programs.html#The-sequence-operator) that combines two expressions (by throwing the result of the first one away and returning the result of the second one). This is not what you want here.